# “Copy to” and “Move to” context menu options in Nautilus3

Tags: nautilus, menu

I used to remove the actions I do not need in good old nautilus2 by editing the `/usr/share/nautilus/ui/nautilus-directory-view-ui.xml` file. Is there any way to modify the context menu in the latest nautilus3 Ubuntu 12.04?